# Android. Вылетает приложение при нажатии кнопки

Tags: java, android

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.changing;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ConstraintLayout layout;
    private Button button1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int color = Integer.parseInt("fff000");
        layout.setBackgroundColor(color);


    }});

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Читай в логах почему вылетает

Comment: вообще нет нужды переводить hex в десятичное число, чтобы потом использовать, как цвет. Можно сразу использовать то, что есть - ``layout.setBackgroundColor(0xfff000)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня всё сработало с добавлением второго аргумента (16) к Integer.parseInt().
MainActivity.java:

```
package com.androidapp.example;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ConstraintLayout layout;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        defineComponents();
        defineFunctionality();
    }

    /**
     * определение функциональности
     */
    private void defineFunctionality() {
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int color = Integer.parseInt("fff000", 16);
                layout.setBackgroundColor(color);
            }});
    }

    /**
     * получение ссылок на графические компоненты
     */
    private void defineComponents() {
        layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Кнопка"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Приложение запускается, фон чёрный, посередине кнопка. При нажатии на кнопку фон становится белым.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer.parseInt("fff000")
```

выкидывает экспешн, что логично потому что строка `fff000` - не парсится на целое число. Хорошим тоном является обертка таких мест блоком `try-catch`

Как вариант надо парсить

```
Integer.parseInt("fff000", 16) //парсим как hex `
```

Или так:

```
Integer.parseInt("0xfff000")` //даем понять парсеру что число hex
```

Comment: к сожалению не помогло, при нажатии на кнопку приложение вылетает и крашеться

Comment: @koki, на вкладке Logcat во время падения будет много красного текста, с ссылками на код, приложите пожалуйста этот красный текст в вопрос, тогда отвечающим будет проще локализовать проблему

Comment: @Barmaley "или так" не работает так